# Can't hide table row using display:none

Tags: html, css

`style="display:none;"` somehow does not work in below example, how is it not working?

I also need the below hierarchy by the way.

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr style="display:none;">
                  <div>
                    Example Row 1:
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    #1#
                  </div>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display:none;">
                  <div>
                    Example Row 2:
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    #2#
                  </div>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `div` is not a valid child of `tr`. If you fix your markup, you'll find your style works as expected.

Comment: @George thank you for the information. Had to use tables to create a PDF, since the tool I'm working with doesn't fully supports `flex-box` properties. And I haven't worked that much with tables. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `td` tag

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr style="display:none;">
                <td>
                  <div>
                    Example Row 1:
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    #1#
                  </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display:none;">
                <td>
                  <div>
                    Example Row 2:
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    #2#
                  </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The total html is working itself up to 3k lines, I could not see this. Thanks again!